# Power BI Subtotal Measure

Tags: excel, filter, powerbi, powerquery

I need your help with some Power Bi code

As you can see, in the Excel Worksheet i have 2 cells (yellow) that are mainly of subtotals and 2 columns (last 2) that depends of these subtotals, however when I upload the data to Power Bi, those formulas are lost, are there any way that in Power Bi can work? considering that those subtotals can be obtained by multiple filters, such as by shirt (product column) and L (Size column) or shirt (product column), L (Size column) and Yellow (Color Column), etc.

Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YgK4C8GEmLdNbvOz4wR3cFjKX9_U2OQfwoHSxebCWbE/edit?usp=sharing

I have seen videos for subtotals but they are just for visuals, not for analyze.

Comment: Where do you want your subtotals to be?

Comment: The only one I'll be using for visual would be the payment termn (Cell G1) as a Visual Card. The other won´t be shown

Comment: Right, so the ones that won't be shown - where do you want them to be?

Comment: I am not sure I understand you correctly. Are you trying to create calculated columns? [Here's how you do it in Power BI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-tutorial-create-calculated-columns), and [here's how you do it in Power Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/add-custom-column). The subtotal you are depending on would be incorporated into the calculation.